# Compression of Request using nginx

Tags: nginx, gzip, compression, http-compression

Using Nginx with Tomcat, we can compress response but I would like to know how to compress request?

In prior versions of NGnix, it was not supported, is it supported in latest versions?

If so, any documentation on how to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

gzip in your nginx conf has to be activated cf
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html

And to allow **request** body compression, http 1.1 has to be used:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_http_version

Arfy